# How are inserts into a temp table reported in a SQL Server trace

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #names (
     [name] nvarchar(max)
     );

INSERT INTO #names ([name])
SELECT CustomerName from CustomerInformation
Where status=3
```

Will the INSERT INTO #names... show up in a SQL Server trace as an INSERT to a table in tempdb or a select from CustomerInformation.  Or will both show up in the trace?

Basically, will the trace show the statement as a insert or a select?

Comment: You can't specify an existing table if you use `SELECT ... INTO` - there's no need for the CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what event you're actually looking for in the Trace:

- [SQL:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) and [SP:StmtCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189570.aspx) will show the statement that executed: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`
- [SQL:BatchCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) will show the complete SQL batch (request) that executed: `CREATE TABLE ...; INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`.

Other events enabled in the Trace will show up accordingly (locks, security audits, query plans etc etc). But the gist of your question is: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` is **one** single statement, not two statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement will appear in the trace once, exactly as you enter it.  The database associated with the statement will be the current database when the command is executed.  Since you don't specify a database in the FROM clause, the current database will be the database where the CustomerInformation table resides.